# Error "mail has already been taken" shows up twice on sign up with Security Extension for Devise (RoR)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am using devise with security extension to validate strong passwords.

When I try to registrate an account with an already taken email, I get the error "email has already been taken" twice in the errors hash.

My user model looks like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
  # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  # :trackable deleted
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :secure_validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :firstname, :lastname, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me
end
```

Without the security extension (`:validatable` instead of `:secure_validatable`) I get the error only once.

What am I doing wrong?

---

P.S. Bonus Question:

How do I prevent certain errors from being raised in the first place? Do I have to manipulate devise's RegistrationsController or is there an option for this?

Comment: Have you found a solution ?

Comment: Yeah, I dropped security extension and created my own custom password validation.

Answer (score 5):

Had the same problem.

Check if this helps: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/plataformatec-devise/S0nxv7BK10M

Comment: Thank you! For those who can't visit the link (anyone in China or Iran for instance), you will see this problem if you use the validatable module, and then add your own presence validation to the email field. This will mean that you have two email validations.

Answer (score 1):

The real reason why this happens is that devise_security_extension defines email uniqueness validator two times.

The first time is when it defines a uniqueness validator for a default login field. The second time is when it defines uniqueness validator for an email field.

When your default login field is email, which is quite common, the validator is defined twice.

I fixed this by putting the following code into an initializer file. It prevents the unnecessary validator from being created when email is your login attribute.

```
module Devise
  module Models
    module SecureValidatable
      module ClassMethods
        private

        def has_uniqueness_validation_of_login?
          return true if login_attribute == :email
          super
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably also have :validatable module active. If you mention it in the devise settings, :secure_validatable skips those basic checks(email:presence, uniqueness and password: presence) and it only shows the error once.

devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :secure_validatable, :validatable